# Cannot install .apk on device

Tags: android, installation, apk

for a long time i was installing [.apk](/questions/tagged/.apk) on my device with no problem!The last days for every app that i try to install the next problem appears! In the console i see the message Installing myapp.apk for 3 minutes and after that i get the following messages:

```
Failed to install myapp.apk on device 'My device' 
(null) 
Launch canceled!
```

Any solution or possible error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to occure sometimes when using adb.

There should be a timeout for the adb to react. If you're doing it with an AVD image, just restart that. If you're doing it with a device, just try to restart it (restart, not just turn it off and on again - that will not properly close all apps due to fast boot in newer Android versions). Works fine for me each time I get this problem.

Comment: how do i restart the device?

Comment: Long press the power button and then select from the context menu...